# Is there a Windows Service Bus 1.1 SDK for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm using https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node which works fine with Azure.
However it doesn't work with on-prem Windows Service Bus 1.1

How do I connect to local Service Bus 1.1 from Node.js?